# visual studio 2019 c++ - concept identifier is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-concepts

I have tried to use concepts in my cpp project which I write using visual studio 2019 version 16.4.1 but I get and error message: "identifier conecpt is undefined".
As far as I know concepts have support in visual studio 2019 since version 16.3 so I cant understand why it still doesn't work for me.

Here is the code I have written, Is there any foolish syntax error in it?

```
#include<concepts>
template<typename T>
concept has_type_member = requires { typename T::type; }
```

If not has anyone have had such a problem and have managed to overcome it?

Comment: Are you using `/std:c++latest`? Intellisense gives me the "error" too, but when compiling there's no error.

Comment: thank you a lot!! apparently I was using the default option which is /std:c++14 in visual studio 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++20 Concepts are now supported for the first time in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 Preview 2.

According to the [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-concepts-are-here-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/):

> First, we’re debuting the feature via /std:c++latest mode and once we
> have all C++20 features implemented across all Visual Studio products
> (compiler, library, IntelliSense, build system, debugger, etc.), we’ll
> provide them through a new /std:c++20 mode. IntelliSense support is
> not currently available and our implementation doesn’t yet include
> recent changes in the ISO C++ standards meeting in Cologne.

I suggest you should try to use `/std:c++latest` mode.

You can set this at Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard > Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)