# Visual Studio for C++ - identifier "concept" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-concepts

I am using the latest version of Windows 10 and Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.4.6). In my project properties, I have the C++ version set to `/std:c++latest`.

However, when I try to use C++20 concepts, I always get `identifier "concept" is undefined` even though I `#include <concepts>`. For a concrete example, here is the first example from cppreference which produces such error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a) {
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) }->std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379735/visual-studio-2019-c-concept-identifier-is-undefined) post, however the solution does not work for me as I already have the configuration suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Compiles fine with MSVC on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/5vejuC

Comment: Are you getting an error from the compiler or intellisense? The latter is not updated to accommodate for the c++20 language features.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I know it is supposed to work with MSVC, however it is not working for me, and I'm not sure how to resolve the issue

Comment: Intellisense shows an error but it compiles fine for me.

Comment: Ahhh, ya that was the issue; IntelliSense. I did not think of that, thank you!

Comment: I come from a time where intellisense was unreliable. Crashing, freezing, showing unrelated errors, and most often using some cached, outdated source code (that was fun). And yes, lagging behind the compiler on the C++11 features. So I learned early on to not rely entirely on intellisense and know that the actual compiler has the last word. Anyway this long introduction is to tell that I am always baffled at people getting stopped in their tracks because they see intellisense errors and confuse them with compiler errors.

Comment: @RichardRobinson I strongly suggest you write a quick answer so that the question doesn't remain opened & unanswered.